# object_recognition_kitchen with Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, object-recognition-kitchen, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**How can I use the object_recognition_kitchen with Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and Asus Xtion?**

I tried install the ORK using binary (sudo apt install ros-kinetic-object-recognition-*) succesfully.

But, it is not include tabletop and has error while running tod.

[Error message]

Mesh and object is founded on CouchDB. I am check it.

```
byeongkyu@byeongkyu-iMac:~$ rosrun object_recognition_core training -c `rospack find object_recognition_tod`/conf/training.ork
Training 1 objects.
computing object_id: 96562faf31b4165800bb3f68d5006aeb
byeongkyu@byeongkyu-iMac:~$ 
byeongkyu@byeongkyu-iMac:~$ rosrun object_recognition_core detection -c `rospack find object_recognition_tod`/conf/detection.ros.ork
[ INFO] [1472790930.085746566]: Initialized ROS. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472790930.458528179]: System already initialized. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472790930.863419206]: System already initialized. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472790930.871813965]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/depth/camera_info [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472790930.876186903]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/depth/image_raw [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472790930.881230116]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/rgb/camera_info [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472790930.885333776]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/rgb/image_raw [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472790931.620373761]: publishing to topic:/recognized_object_array
Loading models. This may take some time...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/object_recognition_core/detection", line 24, in 
    run_plasm(args, plasm)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ecto/opts.py", line 85, in run_plasm
    sched.execute(options.niter)
ecto.CellException:            exception_type  CellException
[cell_name] = pipeline1

[cell_type] = ecto::py::BlackBox

[function_name] = process_with_only_these_inputs

[type] = std::runtime_error

[what] =            exception_type  CellException
[cell_name] = Matcher

[function_name] = process_with_only_these_inputs

[type] = std::runtime_error

[what] = Object Not Found : http://localhost:5984/object_recognition/占쏙옙e

[when] = While triggering param change callbacks




terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And. I am tried also install using rosinstall. reference [http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install]

But, it is failed to running tabletop, tod.

[Error Message]

```
byeongkyu@byeongkyu-iMac:~$ rosrun object_recognition_core detection -c `rospack find object_recognition_tabletop`/conf/detection.object.ros.ork
[ INFO] [1472793255.037448839]: Initialized ROS. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472793255.416741080]: System already initialized. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472793255.777974609]: System already initialized. node_name: /object_recognition_server
[ INFO] [1472793255.792620349]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/depth_registered/camera_info [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472793255.796001824]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/rgb/camera_info [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472793255.799017281]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/depth_registered/image_raw [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
[ INFO] [1472793255.802311035]: Subscribed to topic:/camera/rgb/image_rect_color [queue_size: 1][tcp_nodelay: 0]
133 :: 0.5 , 1 , 0.995004 , /base_link , /head_mount_kinect_rgb_optical_frame
[ INFO] [1472793256.744593721]: publishing to topic:/tabletop/clusters
[ INFO] [1472793256.745550347]: publishing to topic:/table_array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/byeongkyu/catkin_ws/src/ork/ork_core/apps/detection", line 24, in 
    run_plasm(args, plasm)
  File "/home/byeongkyu/catkin_ws/src/ork/ecto/python/ecto/opts.py", line 85, in run_plasm
    sched.execute(options.niter)
ecto.CellException:            exception_type  CellException
[cell_name] = pipeline2

[cell_type] = ecto::py::BlackBox

[function_name] = process_with_only_these_inputs

[type] = std::runtime_error

[what] =            exception_type  CellException
[cell_name] = 

[function_name] = process_with_only_these_inputs

[type] = std::runtime_error

[what] = value type is 0 not 2

[when] = While triggering param change callbacks




terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argumen
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242954/object_recognition_kitchen-with-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2016-10-05**:
Same problem for me after migrating to Kinetic. Tabletop worked fine on indigo.
A bit of debugging points to ModelReaderBase class; maybe the way couchDB stores objects has changed?
You can try to ask also on [ORK Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/object-recognition-kitchen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been fixed: https://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_core/issues/45

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0